# Link Title tag displays through an ajax hover element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<figure class="thumb">
    <a href="#" class="thumb-link" title="My title">
        <img src="small-png.png" alt="My alt">
    </a>...
```

When someone hovers this link, jQuery enlarges the image (gets it with ajax and throws it into the DOM), and the code starts looking like this:

```
<figure class="thumb">
    <a href="#" class="thumb-link" title="My title">
        <img src="small-png.png" alt="My alt">
    </a>
    <div class='thumb-hover' display: 'block'>
        <img>...</img>
    </div> //the image was loaded
```

The thumb-hover z-index is 999, and it is showing above the small-png like it should, however the link TITLE text shines through the big preview image and since it is rather large, it blocks half of it!

The problem still persists if the thumb-hover is loaded before the initial .thumb-link.
Is there any way to control the Title text positioning? Any ideas?

Possible solutions that came into my mind this far:

- Cache title tag information on element hover, removing it the figure child img using jQuery and then restore on mouseout, but that solution looks so ugly.

My goal is to avoid using JS with this.

Update: check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fV5H2/). If you hover on it long enough you will see what I mean.

Comment: I don't get your question, also, `</img>` is incorrect

Comment: thats just an example, of course it is img src etc

Comment: It's not really clear where the alt text comes into it. Ideally, post a link or demo.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Alt text should only be shown when it can't display the image. What does displaying another image over it have to do with that?

Comment: Buddy that's not called AJAX. For it to be called "AJAX", there must be some kind of http request from a server. That's just a simple JavaScript task.

Comment: The alt is visible when the image is not loaded yet, right? Why don't you wait the image to load?

Comment: dump the alt tag and control it w js...

Comment: fiddled it, check out the corrected question

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger the image load, store down the alt value of the image element in a variable.

Then, set the images alt value to an empty string. When you mouse out of the image and hide the thumb, re-apply the alt value you previously stored.

I store the old alt-value in "data-alt" attribute with jquery .data()